# window.showModalDialog issue

Tags: asp.net

I am opening a popup window using and passing some array of parameters

```
window.showModalDialog("Test.aspx", MyArgs, WinSettings);
```

in the Test.aspx i have button, on button click i have "Response.write("Test") when i click on the Test button a new window is getting opened.
Can this be avoided?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this in the `<head>` section of the modal window

```
<base target=_self>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is to make an iframe-page that simply load Test.aspx into the iframe. However, then you need to pass, or access, the MyArgs array to to the page in some manners.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the button in the popup window, what do you want to do? Using:

```
Response.write("Test")
```

Is server-side ASP code - which is likely ***not*** what you want.  If you want to write to the page, you likely want something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myElem = document.getElementById('someDiv');
  myElem.innerHTML = '<b>Hello World!</b>';
</script>
```